# Why isn't the positive lookup working in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know why is the result be false even though three of these positive lookups appear to be true?

```js
let sampleWord = "bana12";
let pwRegex = /(?=^[^0-9])(?=\w{5,})(?=[0-9]{2})/; // Change this line
let result = pwRegex.test(sampleWord);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't chain lookaheads like that. `foo(?=a)(?=b)(?=c)` does not mean `foo` followed by `a` then `b` then `c`, it means `foo` followed by `a`, also followed by `b`, also followed by `c`. So, your code requires that the string starts with a non-number, and 5 alphanumeric characters, and 2 numbers, which is clearly not possible.

Comment: but three of the lookaheads also satisfy the string indepandantly. isnt putting the three lookaheads together meant setting three conditions for the string?

Comment: The lookaheads require that the satisfying conditions are at the start of the portion. The two numbers are **not** at the start of the string. If you want to require that they're anywhere, then use `.*[0-9]{2}` instead.

Comment: oh i see so does that mean that the satisfying portions are from left to right in lookaheads and will it work if i put the 2 digits at the start of the string?